# IOS Custom UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, object, uibutton

I currently work on a small application in which I have several `UIButton`s. Each of them has an `UIImageView` beneath it. At the moment, I associate each `UIButton` with each `UIImageView` (all are named via an `IBOutlet` - `UIButton` and `UIImageView`). When I press a button, the underlying image changes. I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to create a button which contains an underlying `UIImage` (not a `UIButton` image or background image), a sort of new object.

This image is slightly larger than the associated `UIButton`, like the apple calculator basic apps, and this image changes when I press the button.

I've tried several solutions (certainly incomplete) and I'm beginning to despair.

My current solution is functional but I do find it not particularly elegant.

Comment: I tried to help with the grammar and spelling without changing your intended meaning.  Please edit back if you feel that I messed anything up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIButton` has both `image` and `backgroundImage` as its properties.

To achieve what you are looking for, I would actually recommend you to stick to just a `UIButton`, and then using `contentInset` to position the `image` over the `backgroundImage` so it creates the effect I think you are looking for. This should be quite easy in interface builder...

Answer (score 0):

you can make an invisible button and behind it make the image..

This will give you what you want but should be avoided at cost...

**Stick to `UIButton`..**

I believe even in calculator app they are only UIButtons and nothing else..
they have been coded to been momentary selected ..so that's why you see them kind of changing highlight for a small fraction and each button have been coded to perform specific function(+ - / equal .)

**Update : i might be in doubt but if you asked for a button to have an image view inside it..**

then here is the answer.

Make UIbutton. Make an ImageView and then call [theButton.view addSubview:ImageView];

Since both UIbutton and UIImage view inherit from UIView.. you can add as many subviews to them..that is inside them

Comment: It's an interesting pist to explore, I'll try it ... thanks ! If you have others ideas ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct then you may try the following:

UIButton *button = [UIButton alloc]init];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; when button not pressed

[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected]; when button tapped

[button release];